# Polymer Paper-Input not working or rendering

Tags: javascript, html, css, polymer

I am trying to use the paper-input element in my page, but it didn't seem to work.
I then tried to run the code for the demo on the Polymer site, but that didn't work either, and I was getting simple text fields rather than Polymer's paper-input element. I am using the exact same code as the sample i.e.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=yes">

  <title>paper-input</title>

  <script src="..components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.js"></script>

  <link href="..components/paper-input/paper-autogrow-textarea.html" rel="import">
  <link href="..components/paper-input/paper-input-decorator.html" rel="import">
  <link href="..components/paper-input/paper-input.html" rel="import">

  <style shim-shadowdom>

    body {
      font-family: RobotoDraft, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial;
      font-size: 14px;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 24px;
      -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
      -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    }

    section {
      padding: 20px 0;
    }

    section > div {
      padding: 14px;
      font-size: 16px;
    }

    paper-input {
      width: 80%;
    }

    paper-input-decorator {
      max-width: 80%;
    }

    @media only screen and (min-width : 320px) {
      paper-input {
        width: 100%;
      }

      paper-input-decorator {
        max-width: 100%;
      }
    }

    paper-input.narrow {
      width: 150px;
    }

    .custom /deep/ ::-webkit-input-placeholder {
      color: #f4b400;
    }

    .custom /deep/ ::-moz-placeholder {
      color: #f4b400;
    }

    .custom /deep/ :-ms-input-placeholder {
      color: #f4b400;
    }

    .custom /deep/ .label-text,
    .custom /deep/ .error {
      color: #f4b400;
    }

    .custom /deep/ .unfocused-underline {
      background-color: #f4b400;
    }

    .custom[focused] /deep/ .floated-label .label-text {
      color: #0f9d58;
    }

    .custom /deep/ .focused-underline {
      background-color: #0f9d58;
    }

    .custom.invalid /deep/ .floated-label .label-text,
    .custom /deep/ .error {
      color: #f06292;
    }

    .custom.invalid /deep/ .focused-underline {
      background-color: #f06292;
    }

    .custom {
      color: #1a237e;
    }

  </style>

</head>
<body unresolved>

  <section>

    <div>Standalone</div>

    <br>

    <paper-input label="label"></paper-input>

    <br>

    <paper-input label="floating label" floatingLabel></paper-input>

    <br>

    <paper-input label="disabled" disabled></paper-input>

  </section>

  <section>

    <div>Decorator</div>

    <br>

    <paper-input-decorator label="with core-input">
      <input is="core-input">
    </paper-input-decorator>

    <br>

    <paper-input-decorator label="with core-input + floatingLabel" floatingLabel>
      <input is="core-input">
    </paper-input-decorator>

    <br>

    <paper-input-decorator label="with autogrowing text area">
      <paper-autogrow-textarea>
        <textarea></textarea>
      </paper-autogrow-textarea>
    </paper-input-decorator>

    <br>

    <paper-input-decorator label="with autogrowing text area + floatingLabel" floatingLabel>
      <paper-autogrow-textarea>
        <textarea></textarea>
      </paper-autogrow-textarea>
    </paper-input-decorator>

  </section>

  <section>

    <div>Auto-Validation</div>

    <paper-input-decorator label="required" floatingLabel error="input is required!" autoValidate>
      <input is="core-input" required>
    </paper-input-decorator>

  </section>

  <section>

    <div>Custom styling</div>

    <br>

    <paper-input class="custom" label="paper-input"></paper-input>

    <br>

    <paper-input-decorator class="custom" label="decorator">
      <input is="core-input">
    </paper-input-decorator>

  </section>

  <script>

    document.body.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
      console.log('change', e.target);
    });

  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that I kept on getting a 404 (element not found exception) for CORE-INPUT in this case, which seemed a bit odd. But apparently, you need to have core-input imported first before you can use paper-input and that is how I made it work.